# What is a good duct tape for cold weather?

Tags: duct-tape, tape

I want to keep a roll of duct tape in my car for emergencies. I am in NY and some winter days are below freezing. I found an ["all weather" duct tape](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Duck-Pro-1-88-in-x-45-yds-Silver-All-Weather-Duct-Tape-286258/304720779) that has a min hold temperature of 25F but min application temperature of 50F. I have been unable to find many other duct tapes min application temperatures. I wrote the 'Duck' company that makes duct tapes and they told me the tape with the lowest minimum application temperature is 50F and that adhesives just don't work well below that point.

Is there any duct tape that can be applied in cold weather? What tape do you guys use in cold weather?

Comment: I know there are foil tapes which perform in cold temperature... And those are the sorts that you would use on ducts... What sort of things do you use this tape for?

Comment: Plastic zip ties may be more useful in some situations... or copper wire etc

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: While shopping is verboten, OP is asking about types of tape, not specific brands. Yeah it could slop over.  I'm inclined to let it ride.

Comment: It would be better to ask about a particular emergency. Here you aren't asking how to solve a problem, but for a product recommendation. Also, you're a fair distance from home improvement (thought there may be practical overlap).

Comment: fwiw, i find electrical tape to stick better on frozen stuff. maybe it just self-grips better, or maybe being small enough to keep in my pocket, it goes on warmer. It does get hard soon, but i have little trouble applying it.

Comment: The adhesive that gorilla tape uses cures in the presence of water.  in many cases, excess condensate is the cause for poor tape performance in the winter.

Comment: Keeps some other tools in the car as well.  Don't want to get stopped and have a trunk with nothing but Duct tape, rope and zip ties, lol.

Comment: Keep the tape in your car down by where the heat comes into the passenger compartment. That should keep it toasty warm and plenty sticky...

Comment: +1 @SherwoodBotsford, material selection is 100% essential to a safe and successful project. This forum pretends that "shopping" = material specification advise. It doesn't. Helping a DIYer with understanding the materials requirements for their project (the technical performance and application considerations of materials - the "specification requirements") that will allow for a successful project is substantively no different from advising on code questions. Although this isn't a project per se, this will provide a solution for someone down the road with a home improvement project in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Doing any kind of taping in cold weather is difficult. The specifics vary by brand as much as by type. I suggest you buy small rolls, stuff into your deep freeze, then attempt to use. This will allow you to reject types/brands that are impossible to get off the roll. By putting various sample surfaces in the freezer with them, you can test for adhesion to various surfaces.

Start with a google search for "cold weather tape" including the quotes for find tapes that are specifically meant for this use.

Problems associated with taping in cold weather:

- The tape sticks too well to itself, and is difficult to get off the roll.
- The tape doesn't stick to much of anything including itself, once peeled free.
- Objects have frost on them, making adhesion difficult.
- Fingers are cold and clumsy doing a job that can be tough enough with working fingers.

Tapes to try:

- Common duct tape.
- Gorilla tape.  I think they use a different adhesive.
- Gaffer's tape.  Used in the movie/vid/audio industry.  Doesn't leave a residue when removed.
- Fiberglass reenforced clear tape.  If it doesn't stick, tie it.  Note:  You cannot break this by hand.  Requires a cutter.
- Electrical (vinyl) tape

Alternative fastenings

- zip ties.  Note that the cold fingers problems can be acute with these.
- double sided vecro tape. Has hooks on one side, loops on the other.
- Small diameter rope -- paracord.  Avoid the coarse weave poly propylene rope.  Even at room temperature getting a knot to hold can be tricky.
- Baling wire. (black iron wire about 1 mm diameter) easy to bend.
- Snare wire. Finer, and stiffer than baling wire, usually galvanized or brass plated. Doesn't rust for a while.
- shipping cling wrap.

Caution:

Duct tape loses something as it ages. Old duct tape seems to fall in love with itself, and the tape splits along the embedded fabric rather than peel free from the roll.

Comment: I find in cold weather zip ties even high quality heavy duty ones tend to break if they are warm when installed they usually work but if very cold every thing from the lock to the body itself breaks, my apprentice thought I gave him some cheap ones last winter and now he understands why I keep them in the cab of the truck and not in the side boxes that are not heated.

Comment: This is an excellent answer so i will just tack this on. I found a couple of options. https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Venture-Tape-UL181B-FX-Polypropylene-Duct-Tape-1599B/?N=5002385+3293086913&rt=rud  that one seams the best but Gorilla and 3M both make 'ALL WEATHER" duct tape.